# My android app works perfectly at debug. But when I upload the Google-Signed version to the Play Store and download from Play Store, my app crashes

Tags: java, android, crash, google-play, adb

I am new on Android programming, it might seem my question is very basic, but please help me.

First of all, my app is released on the Google Play Store (Internal, Close, Open Tests and Production).

My problem is, when I debug on Android Studio, or install my app from my computer, app works perfectly. But when I upload the Google-Signed version to the Play Store and download from Play Store, my app crashes.

This is why, I logged my Google Play Store downloaded app, and see below lines;

(In more detailed: My main class is Google LVL library example class, I added the Base_64_KEY directly into the area. May it be due to this? When I debug locally, it responds normally and I can start rest of my app without any problem.)

```
2022-08-04 21:17:20.372 17250-17250/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.name, PID: 17250
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at s6.g1.k(:7)
        at h9.h.run(:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
```

Since I use Obfuscation ( `minifyEnabled true`
`shrinkResources true`
), I do not understand where the problem is (i.e. what does it mean `h9.h.run(:1)`). As I know, it is one of the classes in my app, but how should I read it? During the upload to Play Store, it asks me to upload a Debug Symbol List, but how can I supply this (I have already added `debugSymbolLevel =  'FULL'` to my gradle?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I have read lots of similar apk works normal - play store app crash posts, but none of those helped me to identify the issue. Sorry for possible duplicates..

Comment: Android Studio generates a mapping file which helps deobfuscate the crashlogs. Look it up and upload it.

Comment: Debug mode uses a different build. On console you can build a release version using `./gradlew assemblerelease` then install the generated APK file on your phone for testing before uploading to PlayStore.

Comment: Did you turn on proguard?